Credential Manager always returns "GetCredentialCancellationException: activity is cancelled by the user" Google sign in with jetpack
Credential Manager in Android Jetpack Compose always returns "GetCredentialCancellationException: activity is cancelled by the user" when attempting login with google
Hello,
Even when using the web application Id from the console and also having the android key setup, I always get the "activity cancelled by user" error when attempting to login with google in my jetpack compose application. I have looked on other answers mentioning the issues with the client id from the google console but even though they seem set up properly, it is still not working. This is the sign in option I'm using:
val signInWithGoogleOption: GetSignInWithGoogleOption =
        GetSignInWithGoogleOption.Builder(WEB_APPLICATION_ID)
            .build()

And also the libraries:
//google sign in
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:21.1.0'
    implementation "androidx.credentials:credentials:1.2.2"
    implementation "androidx.credentials:credentials-play-services-auth:1.2.2"
    implementation "com.google.android.libraries.identity.googleid:googleid:1.1.0"

Please let me know if you can help me with this issue!

recheck web client id - it should not be android client ID it has to be web

Web Client ID is fine and this actually worked for a few days and then the exception came up again, without changing anything to the IDs

So after debugging for a few hours, I found the main issue.
There’s no need to change anything in your code. Just go to your Google Cloud Console, then remove your app’s OAuth 2.0 Client IDs and recreate them.
You don’t need to change the web application Client IDs.
Google has a limit on OAuth for production-level apps, so this will reset it—and voilà, you should be able to log in!
